# Shouldn't the instructor in this scenario try to avoid a deadstick landing?

Tags: safety, landing

In the Netflix drama "The Crown" (season 1, episode 4) Prince Philip has flight lessons with Group Captain Townsend (below is an image of that scene, I was unable to identify the plane).

[image]

After Prince Philip complains about the noise of the engine, Group Captain Townsend deliberately turns it off, and they both enjoy the silence for a while. After some chat, Prince Philip notices the ground getting closer:

> Prince Philip: "Shouldn't we get her started now? The ground seems terribly close."
>
> Group Captain Townsend: "No, it's too low to restart, sir. We'll do a dead-stick landing."

And they land safely.

My question is: if that was a real event, shouldn't Group Captain Townsend (as the instructor) interrupt the relaxing gliding with a **warning**? Something along the lines of *"excuse me, sir, we're losing altitude, if you want me to restart the engine we have to do it now"*, or even *"I'm restarting the engine now"*. I mean, shouldn't he be checking the limit altitude for restarting the engine?

I'll not ask why Group Captain Townsend didn't do that, it would be *off topic*, opinion-based and, despite the [Group Captain being a real person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Townsend_(RAF_officer)), that scene is fictional anyway (The Crown is not 100% historically accurate). I'm just curious about the most probable behaviour of a real instructor in a situation like that.

Comment: Is your question "what is the lowest altitude to attempt and engine restart on the DH82?". If so, you can edit the title to reflect it, because it is more about engine restart than about landing.

Comment: @ManuH no, that's not my question. My question is why did the instructor wait until the apprentice warned about restarting the engine to say *"it's too late"*.

Comment: OK understood. Thus your question is about the instructor's responsibility, isn't it? Thus you may edit the question to reflect it as it is more about instruction method than about landing.

Comment: The scene is pure TV with no basis in reality I'm afraid. The Tiger Moth has no electric starter, and must be hand propped, so as soon as the engine stopped they were committed to landing in a field. Prince Phillip would have been well aware of that.

Comment: @GdD Like a modern jet or prop engine, if airspeed is sufficient, the propeller will windmill fast enough to allow an unassisted restart. Here, they delayed restart until they were going too slow and too low to dive.

Comment: I agree, once the prop stops it's unlikely you'd get is spinning again @user71659, even with lots of altitude.

Comment: @GdD note that Prince Phillip _should_ have been aware of that. No guarantee he _would_ have been aware of that. ;)

Comment: Just as a practical matter, you aren't going to be enjoying the silence in an airplane like that.  It may be quieter with the engine off, but there's still going to be a lot of wind noise.

Comment: Surprisingly, given the usual high level of knowledge on here, nobody has corrected the "Captain Townsend" error. The RAF officer Peter Townsend, who instructed Prince Philip, and had a romance with Princess Margaret, had the RAF rank of Group Captain. British and British Commonwealth air forces (and certain others) have a different set of rank names from normal army ranks. RAF ranks were created in 1918 and partly based on naval rank names. A Group Captain is equivalent in rank to an naval Captain or an army full Colonel, NATO grade OF-5. The rank is not shortened.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, edited.

Comment: I have a feeling that an RCAF Squadron Leader became a "Major" in 1968 when the Canadian Forces were unified, and had to wear a cockamamie uniform and rank insignia until 2015/2016 when they at least got the RAF-style stripes back, if not (yet?) the rank titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if that was a real event, shouldn't Captain Townsend (as the instructor) interrupt the relaxing gliding with a warning? Something along the lines of "excuse me, sir, we're losing altitude, if you want me to restart the engine we have to do it now", or even "I'm restarting the engine now". I mean, shouldn't he be checking the limit altitude for restarting the engine?

This question appears to be predicated on the idea that the instructor had no plans to land the plane with the engine turned off. Having watched the scene, I'm far less convinced that this is the case. In fact, it's not until Philip remarks that the ground is coming up that the Captain tells him they'll be landing deadstick.

In the series, this instructor featured is a renowned flying ace with huge amounts of combat flying experience including a number of forced landings and ditchings.

[Bob Hoover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Hoover) (who you could argue with cut from a similar cloth) regularly displayed and demonstrated with the engines turned off, up to and including landing in that configuration.* On the basis that turning the engine off was deliberate and not an emergency, I don't think the scene after that point is particularly unrealistic. They appear to be making a straight in approach and land on an airfield - it's entirely plausible the Captain made a deliberate decision to land with no engine from the very start.

*Example:

Comment: I believe you're correct: seeing that way, Townsend never planned to restart the engine... Had not Prince Philip asked about the altitude Townsend would simply do a deadstick landing without anouncing it.

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae I didn't add this to my answer as I couldn't cite anything, but my understanding is that early aviators routinely landed with the engine out. Now obviously that wouldn't be the case in the 50's, but I can imagine a WWII ace, having been taught by an earlier generation, being very comfortable with the idea. Obviously nowadays we value the safety margin and ability to go around far more

Answer (score 2):

That scene is completely unrealistic as you have guessed. When the engine of a single engine airplane fails there's always a chance you may not be able to restart it, so the procedure is to slow to best glide speed, choose a field to land in, and start flying an approach. Next you work through your engine failure restart procedure, and if you can't get it restarted you make a mayday call and prepare for your emergency landing. You want to brief your passengers, stow away loose items and clear your exits, shut off the fuel supply to reduce the chance of a fire. Above all concentrate on flying a stable approach and sticking the landing. At some point attempting a restart becomes a distraction, so you stop trying and concentrate on getting it down safely.

So you'd never think 'this is nice and quiet...' if the engine quits, you'd think 'this is far too quiet!' and take immediate and decisive action. You would never sit blissfully enjoying the silence as that's a great way to die. This is why practice forced landings are a significant part of training, and pilots should continue to practice them.

Regarding that particular scene, the Tiger Moth has no electrical system, so no electric starter. It's got one gravity fed fuel tank, and very little a pilot can do if the engine quits. If it's something a pilot can fix quickly, for instance a lean mixture mixture or accidentally switching off the magnetos a restart is possible if the prop is windmilling, but only if quick action is taken. The characters would have been well aware of this, so the scene isn't realistic.

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer - I feel it lacks the context of the scene and makes a lot of presumptions about the characters motive. In the scene Townsend turns it off completely unprompted and the landing (on a runway) happens very shortly after - given his somewhat exceptional aviation experience, it's just as likely he entirely deliberately to land with the engine off. This wouldn't have been entirely uncommon at one point and his attitude to flight safety would have been very very different to modern flying training.

Comment: I should add, not to say the scene is "realistic" or that it happened like that

Comment: I think discussion of character and motive is getting off topic for this site @Dan. I have had the good fortune to talk to more than one former RAF pilots from that era, and none of them would say the approach to training was blase. The phrase 'you've just had an engine failure' was as common in their training then as it was now, probably more so as engines were less reliable, but the idea that a pilot wouldn't know a dead stick landing was inevitable or have already started to prepare for one lacks credibility.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your point - with all due, have you tried to quickly watch the scene? There's no real insinuation that he didn't know exactly what was coming - to me, after a quick watch, it looks he's set up with the field in front and planned the whole thing. I think you and the OP are reading an emergency or something un expected into a scene which has no such thing. Now whether it's a good idea to turn the engine off - well, that's a different question. But all I see is a deliberate piece of decision making from an expert pilot. And Bob Hoover made an entire career out of that...

Comment: I've watched most of the series @Dan. Well, at least the seasons with that cast. Again, discussions of character, motivation and writer intent are out of place here.

Comment: If they're out of place, then the question is out of place as is your answer. The behaviour of most modern, real instructors would be to never deliberately turn off the engine. But in this series, the character did ad I don't see where the emergency comes from? Like I say, Bob Hoover does half a display like this - I wouldn't do it, nor would anybody I fly with but here we are!

Comment: The question asks what is realistic for an engine failure @Dan, the OP specifically states Townsend's behavior on the show is out of scope for the question.

Comment: But it wasn't an engine failure! What's realistic for an unplanned failure is a completely different question - the engine was deliberately shutdown.

Comment: I disagree with it not being realistic. My CFI shut off the engine on my first (“discovery”) flight, and we weren’t even within gliding distance of an airport. He did have me restart the engine, but only after we were on short final to land in a field if that didn’t work.

Comment: That was not smart on the part of your CFI @StephenS.

Comment: @GdD A few years later he got fired for doing it on a discovery flight with the chief pilot’s kid. But I wasn’t saying it was smart, just that it’s not unrealistic.

Answer (score -2):

First, a real instructor wouldn't have turned the engine off at all. The engine is kind of important, after all.*

Second, you're never "too low" to start the engine. After all, you can start it when you're on the ground, and that's about as low as an airplane can get.

Third, to actually answer your question, yes, if there was some limit to how low they could go, then the instructor should have said something before reaching that point.

The airplane in the screenshot is a [de Havilland DH.82 Tiger Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Tiger_Moth).

*There are some instances of instructors turning the engine off to test their students on emergency engine-out procedures. But that's for that specific purpose, not just because they don't like the engine sound. Note that I'm not going to argue one way or another as to whether or not it's a good idea, just pointing out it does happen.

Comment: well, starting up the engine may take longer than it takes to hit the ground, which would make it too late to start the engine in that specific scenario.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with this answer, at some point you have to abandon restarting the engine and concentrate on the landing.

Comment: Old planes like the Tiger Moth did not have electric starters; they had to be hand propped. There is an altitude/airspeed window where the speed of the windmilling propeller is sufficient to restart in flight. If you are too slow and can't dive to accelerate, then the engine cannot be restarted.

Comment: @GdD That assumes that the engine quit because of a problem with the engine itself. If they just turned the engine off, there's no reason they couldn't just turn it back on.

Comment: @user71659 That's true, I didn't consider that. However, if that was the case, the instructor should have said that they were too **slow** to restart, not too **low**. I've never seen the movie in question, but the OP makes it sound like its an instructor training someone to fly, in which case, clear communication is vital. (Of course, it's also possible that the OP just misheard the dialog.) Also, that would militate even more to the instructor not turning the engine off at all, due to the problems with restarting it.